# Sufficient statistics when mean is known

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, variance

I want to find sufficient statistics for $N(0,\sigma^2)$. I know that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2$ is a sufficient statistics by factorization Theorem. I wonder if $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{X})^2$ which is sample variance is sufficient or not. It seems that it is not sufficient because I couldn't factorize the density but I couldn't prove it.

Comment: What role does $\bar X$ play in sample variance when population mean is known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $T=\sum X_i^2$ and $U=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum (X_i-\bar{X})^2=\frac{\sum X_i^2 -n \bar{X}^2}{n-1}$.

If you want to show a statistic  is not a sufficient statistic  , you can compare it with minimal sufficient statistic. Use the fact that 
[a minimal sufficient statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Minimal_sufficiency)
 is a  function of any  sufficient statistic.

It is obvious that $T=\sum X_i^2$ is a minimal sufficient statistic for $\sigma^2$. Since $T$ is minimal sufficient statistic, so it is a function of any sufficient statistic. It is enough to show that $T$ is not a function of $U$.

$T$ is a function of $U$ if $U(a_1)=U(a_2
)$ $\Rightarrow T(a_1)=T(a_2)$. So it is enough to find two points that $U(a_1)= U(a_2)$  but $T(a_1)\neq T(a_2)$ , and hence $T$ is not a function of $U$  and hence $U$ is not a sufficient  statistic.

$a_1=(x_1=1,x_2=1, \cdots ,x_n=1)$

$a_2=(x_1=0,x_2=0, \cdots ,x_n=0)$

So $0=U(a_1)=U(a_2
)$ but $1=T(a_1)\neq 0=T(a_2
)$